# How to use hidden layer activations to construct loss function and provide y_true during fitting in Keras?

Tags: keras

Assume I have a model like this. M1 and M2 are two layers linking left and right sides of the model.
[The example model: Red lines indicate backprop directions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKFHr.png)

During training, I hope M1 can learn a mapping from L2_left activation to L2_right activation. Similarly, M2 can learn a mapping from L3_right activation  to L3_left activation. 
The model also needs to learn the relationship between two inputs and the output.
Therefore, I should have three loss functions for M1, M2, and L3_left respectively.

I probably can use:

```
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
          loss={'M1': 'mean_squared_error',
                'M2': 'mean_squared_error', 
                'L3_left': mean_squared_error'})
```

But during training, we need to provide y_true, for example:

```
model.fit([input_1,input_2], y_true)
```

In this case, the y_true is the hidden layer activations and not from a dataset. 
Is it possible to build this model and train it using it's hidden layer activations?

Comment: Hey, did you manage to build this model? did it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have **only one output**, you must have **only one loss function**.

If you want **three loss functions**, you must have **three outputs**, and, of course, **three Y vectors** for training.

If you want loss functions in the middle of the model, you must take outputs from those layers.

**Creating the graph of your model: (if the model is already defined, see the end of this answer)**

```
#Here, all "SomeLayer(blabla)" could be replaced by a "SomeModel" if necessary
    #Example of using a layer or a model:
        #M1 = SomeLayer(blablabla)(L12) 
        #M1 = SomeModel(L12)

from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import *

inLef = Input((shape1))   
inRig = Input((shape2))

L1Lef = SomeLayer(blabla)(inLef)
L2Lef = SomeLayer(blabla)(L1Lef)
M1 = SomeLayer(blablaa)(L2Lef) #this is an output

L1Rig = SomeLayer(balbla)(inRig)

conc2Rig = Concatenate(axis=?)([L1Rig,M1]) #Or Add, or Multiply, however you're joining the models    
L2Rig = SomeLayer(nlanlab)(conc2Rig)
L3Rig = SomeLayer(najaljd)(L2Rig)

M2 = SomeLayer(babkaa)(L3Rig) #this is an output

conc3Lef = Concatenate(axis=?)([L2Lef,M2])
L3Lef = SomeLayer(blabla)(conc3Lef) #this is an output
```

**Creating your model with three outputs:**

Now you've got your graph ready and you know what the outputs are, you create the model:

```
model = Model([inLef,inRig], [M1,M2,L3Lef])
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='rmsprop')
```

If you want different losses for each output, then you create a list:

```
#example of custom loss function, if necessary
def lossM1(yTrue,yPred):
    return keras.backend.sum(keras.backend.abs(yTrue-yPred))

#compiling with three different loss functions
model.compile(loss = [lossM1, 'mse','binary_crossentropy'], optimizer =??)
```

But you've got to have three different yTraining too, for training with:

```
model.fit([input_1,input_2], [yTrainM1,yTrainM2,y_true], ....)
```

**If your model is already defined and you don't create it's graph like I did:**

Then, you have to find in `yourModel.layers[i]` which ones are M1 and M2, so you create a new model like this:

```
M1 = yourModel.layers[indexForM1].output
M2 = yourModel.layers[indexForM2].output
newModel = Model([inLef,inRig], [M1,M2,yourModel.output])
```

**If you want that two outputs be equal:**

In this case, just subtract the two outputs in a lambda layer, and make that lambda layer be an output of your model, with expected values = 0.

Using the exact same vars as before, we'll just create two addictional layers to subtract outputs:

```
diffM1L1Rig = Lambda(lambda x: x[0] - x[1])([L1Rig,M1])
diffM2L2Lef = Lambda(lambda x: x[0] - x[1])([L2Lef,M2])
```

Now your model should be:

```
newModel = Model([inLef,inRig],[diffM1L1Rig,diffM2L2lef,L3Lef])
```

And training will expect those two differences to be zero:

```
yM1 = np.zeros((shapeOfM1Output))
yM2 = np.zeros((shapeOfM2Output))
newModel.fit([input_1,input_2], [yM1,yM2,t_true], ...)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Daniel! This is extremely helpful! 
A following question is how can I have [yTrainM1,yTrainM2,yTrainL13]?
Because two of them (yTrainM1, yTrainM2) are the activations of hidden layers (L22, L13), how can I get the the activations during training if I use model.fit()?

I can imagine that without using model.fit(), I can feed a data batch and get the activations. Then train the model using the data batch and the activation that I got using model.train_on_batch(). And I can repeat this procedure using ForLoop. Is this the only possible and most efficient way?

Comment: The outputs are the activations, no? If you are getting the activations as parameters for a loss function, you have to compare them with something, what do you want to compare them with?

Comment: Do you mean "weights" instead of "activations"?

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't make this clear. 
[For example, in this updated figure,](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-JRafo_7DuFo/WRPvjR4sVJI/AAAAAAAABxI/hQFwafSQjhkYf1lL1I5ZbfvqP6d_bexZgCHM/s0/chrome_2017-05-11_13-58-52.png)
I hope M1 can learn to predict the activation of L2_right based on the activation of L2_left. Therefore, after training, the output of M2 should be close to the activation of L2_right.

Comment: To be more clear, when a new data sample enter this model from input_1 and input_2, then, through input -> L1 -> L2, we can have activations of L2_left and L2_right. At this moment, the input and expected output of M1 should be the activations of L2_left and L2_right respectively. Therefore, in your implementation, ***yTrainM1*** should be the activation of L2_right.

Comment: No, yTrainM1 is what you expect that the output of M1 be. In order to create a loss function, you must have an expected value. The loss function will compare the model activation (the predicted M1 output) with the true activation (what you expect the output of M1 to be).

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I totally understand what you said. In usual scenarios, model outputs should be guided by expected outputs which are Y of a dataset. But this is not the case in my model. 
In short, I hope my model can have a small module (e.g. M1) which can use part of the model internal state to predict another part of the model state. For example. in human brains, some neurons can predict sensory neuron activations based on neuron states in motor systems. Therefore, the expected output from M1 is the activation of a specific part of the model (i.e. L2_right).

Comment: So, you want something like `output of M1 = output of L1_right`? And the loss function would be some kind of `mean_squared_error(outputM1, outputL1_right)`?

Comment: Added at the end of the answer this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to answer to the last part: how to make gradients only affect one side of the model.

...well.... at first that sounds unfeasible to me. But, if that is similar to "train only a part of the model", then it's totally ok by defining models that only go to a certain point and making part of the layers untrainable.

By doing that, nothing will affect those layers. If that's what you want, then you can do it:

```
#using the previous vars to define other models

modelM1 = Model([inLef,inRig],diffM1L1Rig)
```

This model above ends in diffM1L1Rig. Before compiling, you must set L2Right untrainable:

```
modelM1.layers[??].trainable = False
#to find which layer is the right one, you may define then using the "name" parameter, or see in the modelM1.summary() the shapes, types etc. 

modelM1.compile(.....)
modelM1.fit([input_1, input_2], yM1)
```

This suggestion makes you train only a single part of the model. You can repeat the procedure for M2, locking the layers you need before compiling.

You can also define a full model taking all layers, and lock only the ones you want. But you won't be able (I think) to make half gradients pass by one side and half the gradients pass by the other side.

So I suggest you keep three models, the fullModel, the modelM1, and the modelM2, and you cycle them in training. One epoch each, maybe....

That should be tested....